# Cual es la diferencia entre clonar un repositorio de github y descargarlo como zip?

Tags: git, github, repositorio, descargar

Estoy empezando a verificar un proyecto que esta en github, que alguien más hizo y quisiera saber si es lo mismo clonarlo o descargarlo como zip. Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Al clonar, autmáticamente descargas todo el historial de cambios (_commits_) y la referencia a  repositorio remoto, permitiendote continuar trabajando en el código y realizar cambios en el mismo, enviarlos, etc.. En el zip solo bajas el código fuente al momento de la descarga (_de ese commit_).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración.